# eclipseLink multitenancy bug: tenant id not added

Tags: eclipselink, multi-tenant

eclipseLink multitenancy bug: tenant id not added. I tried both 2.5.1 and 2.6.1.

For example,

Student and Course: ManyToMany.

```
Student     Course                        Student_Course
-------     ------------------            -----------------
id, name    id, name, tenantId           studentId, courseId


 public class Student {

        @ManyToMany(...)
        List<Course> getCourses() {
            ...
        }
    }
```

Course is multitenancy enabled, but Student is not.

Search student left join course: The generated SQL:

```
    SELECT DISTINCT t1.ID AS a1, t1.NAME AS a2, t1.VERSION AS a3, t0.ID AS a4, 
t0.tenantId AS a5, t0.NAME AS a6, t0.VERSION AS a7 FROM Student t1 LEFT OUTER 
JOIN (Student_Course t2 JOIN Course t0 ON (t0.ID = t2.courseId)) ON 
(t2.studentId = t1.ID) ORDER BY t1.ID DESC
```

The restriction for Course.tenantId is not added into the query.

```
<entity class="Course" > 
    <multitenant>
        <tenant-discriminator-column name="tenantId" context-property="tenant.id"
            discriminator-type="INTEGER"/>      
    </multitenant>  
</entity> 



EntityManager em = ..
em.setProperty("tenant.id", 1);

CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Student> criteriaQuery = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(Student.class);
Root<Student> root = criteriaQuery.from(Student.class);
root.fetch("courses", JoinType.LEFT);

criteriaQuery.distinct(true);
TypedQuery<Student> query = em.createQuery(criteriaQuery);
List<Student> students = query.getResultList();
```

The courses of a retrieved student will contain all the courses of the student from all tenants. But only the courses from tenant 1 is wanted.

Is there any workaround? Thanks.

Comment: Does this work for other queries on the Course entity, or is multitenant config just not working at all?

Comment: Searching on Course works. The Course.tenantId will be added in query SQL. The join from Student is not working. Thanks.

Comment: Show how you are creating the query, as it could be an issue with the api being used, for instance, you might also try reading in course and joining in the Students to see if that helps.  Otherwise, I'd try the latest EclipseLink version then and file a bug.

Comment: The JPA code has been added. Tried the last 2.6.3 version. same results. Thanks.

Comment: Try running the code in a transaction, or marking your Student entities as Protected and the student's course mapping noncacheable: http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.5/jpa/extensions/a_noncacheable.htm

Answer (score 3):

It seems there was a bug 
[Bug 345962 - Join fetch query when using tenant discriminator column fails.](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=345962)

that has been solved in version 2.2.1 of **javax.persistence** which can be found on **version 2.7.3 of [org.eclipse.persistence](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.eclipse.persistence/eclipselink/2.7.3)**

[mvn javax.persistence](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.eclipse.persistence/javax.persistence)